# Upper triangular matrix with empty space in lower triangular

Tags: matrices

How to represent this upper triangular matrix?
[image: Upper triangular matrix]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of the matrix was giving you trouble, but here's a sample:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

\begin{document}

\[
 \Var(\epsilon) =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \Var(\epsilon_1) & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \Cov(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_p) \\
  & \Var(\epsilon_2) & \cdots & \cdots & \Cov(\epsilon_2,\epsilon_p) \\
  & \ddots & \cdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
  & & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots \\
  & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
  & & & & \Var(\epsilon_p)
 \end{bmatrix}
 = \Omega_{(np\times np)}.
\]

\end{document}
```

Notice that I've made `Var` and `Cov` into operators, which affects how they're typeset.  The output:

[image: sample output]